# Is there a way to have jmeter beautify json data within the response data tab?

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm tired of copying **JSON** text from JMeter's "response data" tab into **notepad++** and using the JSON Viewer plugin to make the JSON text readable.

Is there a plugin for JMeter to do this by default?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Its already inside of JMeter. /sigh

Within the "View Results Tree" just above the list is a drop down combo-box and right there is a JSON renderer.

Perhaps this will help the next person who skips over the combo-box.

Comment: isit possible to have Json as a default rather then having to choose it from the drop down menu?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've made changes like this by downloading the complete source and making changes like you've asked.

Comment: nice! I've been using JMeter for quite a while now and was always overlooking this neat option to render JSON responses.

Answer (score 10):

just to visualize D-Klotz's answer, here's the dropdown button (JMeter version: 5.3)
[image]